# android name value pairs for HttpPost

Tags: android, post, name-value

I am new to android and I have a question about name value pairs that I am a little confused on. For example I am trying to post to the following example and get the response code using the endpoint:
     /account/create/bank-id?ssn=SSN&name=NAME&email=EMAIL. I would edit the need to edit the following : bank-id , SSN , NAME, and EMAIL. at the moment. I am thinking along the lines of(so far no luck , no repsponse code are printing so I dont know what I am doing wrong at the moment, ty for any replies):

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xxx.xxx/account/create/");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bank-id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ssn", "451"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "kitty"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "kitty"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

}

Comment: try to print error message in `catch()` tag

Comment: try using response.getEntity() after "HttpResponse response =..." , And ofcourse be sure you get parameters in server side.